# Power Query: How to add column with repeating values

Tags: excel, powerquery, customcolumn

I have an excel table with the fields `ProductCode`, `ProductDescription` and `Sales`. I would like to add a column named "`Store`", where the values come from certain header rows, as seen in the following images.

Thanks!

Original:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AB-S5yD2Ic4xsU8)

Comment: Post a sample file, and I'll help you with the steps

Comment: Thank! I have just edited the post in order to add a sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would extract the store and put it in another column

`Test` in *Source* line is the name of the table

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Test"]}[Content],
    ChangeTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ProductCode", type text}, {"ProductDescription", type text}, {"Sales", Int64.Type}}),
    AddStoreCol = Table.AddColumn(ChangeTypes, "Store", each if [ProductDescription] = null and Text.Start([ProductCode],5) <> "TOTAL" then [ProductCode] else null, type text),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(AddStoreCol,{"Store"}),
    FilterNulls = Table.SelectRows(FillDown, each [ProductDescription] <> null and [ProductDescription] <> "")
in
    FilterNulls
```

Let me know if it works